# Run SignalR server from DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, signalr, signalr-hub

For my project I need an API between two programs to communicate (specifically a WPF desktop app and a UWP app developed with Unity). What I currently have is a SignalR server that's running with both programs subscribed as clients so they can talk to each other.

So far that's working pretty well but I was wondering if I could somehow set up the server in a DLL that the WPF app could consume and control. That would slim down the whole solution and make it a bit more elegant imo.

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: do you have an opportunity to host the signalr server on a web server (IIS)?

Comment: I do but I'd prefer to host it for instance in a console app using owin to keep the overhead low and since everything is running on just one machine anyway.

Comment: @ibubi I'm not shure if I understand your answer correct. You like that your wpf app host a server inside?

Comment: Well I'm developing the UWP app as an extension for an existing WPF app. The changes to the existing program should be minimal. Therefore I need an API with just a few methods and events to enable communication. So yes basically I would like the WPF project to host the server, but without having to write a whole lot of code inside of it.

Comment: WPF desktop applications typically runs on an end users desktop. It doesn't make much sense to run a WPF application on a server. Who is supposed to see the UI? You are probaby better off hosting your SignalR service in a console app or a windows service.

Comment: @mm8 I think I didn't express myself properly. All three programs run on the end user's device (the WPF main-app, the SignalR server as a console-app and the UWP extension). I was just wondering if there's a way to somehow combine main-app and server.

Comment: So your question is basically whether you can host a SignalR server in a .NET desktop application? Yes, you can. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far that's working pretty well but I was wondering if I could somehow set up the server in a DLL that the WPF app could consume and control.

You could implement the SignalR server in a class library that you reference from your WPF application. This is known as a self-hosted SignalR server.

There  is an example available on MSDN that indeed uses a console application to host the service, but you can do the same in a WPF application:

**Tutorial: SignalR Self-Host:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Comment: I went with this approach. Thanks for the help! But I guess ultimately it's a matter of personal taste, if you prefer this or a separate application.

Answer (score 1):

I had an experience similar to yours. I have hosted signlar server on a web api app. A windows form application connects to signlar server as client, and a console application sends data via posting to an endpoint of web api and inside api the data is brodacasted to the connected client/s. *(In my case, I have one direction data transfer)*

Creating a standalone signalr server(either hosting on iis or self host) is the right choice I think. 
First of all, your code is neat, you are able to maintain the code indepentenly from the other projects. Your application will not be dependent to another application, so you won't suffer if your wpf or uwp application crashes, on the other hand your signalr server will down too and it is bad if the signalr server should always be up and running.

As nearly as I can tell, I can't see any disadvantage of aparting signalr server from the other applicatons, if you worked on seperate physical machines, maybe I would tell that there will be network latencies if it is important for you.

So, divide and conquer!